# how to use javascript to render jinja or jinja2 template

Tags: javascript, jinja2

Can I use javascript language render a jinja template?

Like replace the python code below with javascript:

```
from jinja2 import Template
template = Template('Hello {{ name }}!')
template.render(name='John Doe')
u'Hello John Doe!'
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking specifically about Jinja templates or are you after a templating system _like_ Jinja?

Comment: better be jinja templates, or another templating system will be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't since it's python. Not easily anyway.

There are ports such as [this](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) and [this](https://github.com/sstur/jinja-js)

The first one is what I have personally used and can vouch for being in feature parity.